# How to evaluate Jinja2 context variable as a literal string?

Tags: javascript, jinja2

I am passing the following value to a Jinja2 template from Python:

```
context = {}
if 'start_date' in request.values:
    context['start_date'] = request.values['start_date']
return render_template('index.html', **context)
```

Where in `index.html`, I have the following Javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log({{start_date}});
        {% if start_date %}
        START_DATE = {{start_date}};
        {% else %}
        START_DATE = null;
        {% endif %}
    </script>
```

The intention is that the variable `start_date` will be a string that is passed to the Javascript code further as the constant `START_DATE`. However, when I load the page with the `start_date=2013-01-01` in the GET, for example, I get the print `2011` in the console: looks like Jinja2 evaluates the value as an arithmetic expression and returns the result of 2013 − 1 − 1 = 2011.

How can I force Jinja2 to evaluate this string literally rather than as a numerical expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like javascript is evaluating the date as a subtraction of ints.  If you wrap {{start_date}} in quotes, this will not happen.  Rather, this will allow your date to be recognized as a string.

Comment: Of course! It's Javascript doing the evaluation, not Jinja. If I'd just write "2013-1-1" in Javascript, of course I'd need quotes for it not to be interpreted as an arithmetic expression. What Jinja does is simply string substitution then.

Comment: As a side note, I would suggest that you sanitize your data before sending it out to your template.  This is a perfect example where an XSS attack could occur.